# Permission Handler - Storage Permission Not Working

Tags: android, flutter, permissions

I want user permission to read and write on external storage. I have used  "Permission Handler" dependency v5.0.1+1 but failed to get storage permission. I have declared Read n Write storage permission in android manifest and have set minSdk to 23, target and compile sdk set to 30 in build file.
Error Encounter:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method requestPermissions on channel flutter.baseflow.com/permissions/method

Comment: can u post code what you have tried so far?

Comment: You are testing on an Android 10 device.

Comment: @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkPermission();
  }
checkPermission() async {
    if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
      print("Permission granted");
    } else {

      Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
        Permission.storage,
      ].request();
      print(statuses[Permission.storage]);
    }

Answer (score 0):

You're getting ***MissingPluginException*** because platform-specific code is not generated

Just run ***flutter clean*** command and rebuild the app